# Domain name record with a /somethinghere.aspx

Tags: domains

I'm not very savvy with domain names.

Basically I have a dedicated Windows hosting server for a web application that is located at a location like this:

123.234.345.456/script.aspx

I need to map a domain name to this location. Don't ask why I can't just map it straight to the ip address - I didn't create the application and the index page isn't in use. I just have to map it to the specific script.

How would I do this using A records? (or MX records, or CNAME or SPF - those are the options I have). I don't have any nameservers.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DNS cannot resolve to individual pages; however, your server can decide what is served up to a client who does not request a specific page. As you mentioned, this is usually index.xxx or default.xxx, depending on what server you use. But, there is a way to do what you're looking for.

### Step 1: DNS

So, first things first; as Matthew Brookes mentioned in his answer, you'll need to create an A record for that IP address. If this is the only thing on that domain, you probably want to use **@** as your host, which is a wildcard. If I visit example.com, or thisrecorddoesnotexist.example.com, it will direct you to the IP you set in this record.

This will get you the example.com/script.aspx address, but won't take people directly to it, which brings us to Step 2.

### Step 2: Default Document

I'm assuming you're using IIS, because of the aspx filename. Anyways, you can set the **Default Document** of your web site to something other than default.aspx or default.htm.

In IIS properties, under the web site in question, click the 'Documents' tab (Note: This is in IIS6, don't know if 7 is different) and add your script name to the default documents, at the top. That way, whenever someone visits example.com, they will be presented with your script by default.

### Step 3: Couldn't do Step 2

Not everybody has access to configure their server, especially if you're using shared hosting of some kind. So, as a backup, you could always create a default.aspx document that [redirects the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093081/aspx-page-to-redirect-to-a-new-page) to the correct page. This wouldn't require any additional server configuration.

### Step 4: Profit

So, I think that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: This was how we had to do it in the end. I got the dev to make a default.aspx that redirected to the script and set the a record to the server. Now, had a funny issue which was that we had to change the nameservers, even though I'd set an a record. I was under the impression that an a record overrode the the nameservers?

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: Nameserver records contain the address of the DNS servers that should be queried for your domain, so they do get checked before the A records.

Answer (score 2):

MX records are for email so thats out. 
SPF records relate to email as well ([Sender Policy Framework](http://www.openspf.org/))

So that leaves you with an A record or a CNAME. I normally use a CNAME if i am not provided with an IP address. Therefore i would opt for an A record.

One thing you have not indicated is whether you have a Domain Name already?? If not you will need to purchase one of those through a domain register i would look for one which gives you full DNS control you can then use that to point the Domain Name at the IP address you have using an A record.  The company who you purchase the domain name though normally act as your Name Servers as well.

Comment: Yes, I have the domain name. :) Thanks, the problem is the dns won't let me make an A record with a / in it.